# How random is this password-generating algorithm?

Tags: python, random, python-2.x, windows

This code's sole purpose is to create a very random password, using letters and numbers.

I think that it fulfills its purpose, but I wonder, could it be done better? I'm not talking about efficiency, but security.

In your eyes, how secure is this method for generating passwords, and if it is barely secure at all, what better practices are there for this sort of thing?

```
import random  as r
import sys
import os
from subprocess import call
alpha_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alpha_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
call('color a', shell=True)
class MutateSeed(object):
    def __init__(self, seed, alpha_lower, alpha_upper):
        self.seed = seed
        self.mutated_seed = []
        self.alphabet_lower = list(alpha_lower)
        self.alphabet_upper = list(alpha_upper)
    def mutate_seed(self):
        for x in range(self.seed):
            a = r.randint(0, 9)
            b = r.randint(0, 9)
            c = r.randint(0, 9)
            d = r.randint(0, 25)
            e = r.randint(0, 25)
            f = r.randint(0, 25)

            con = r.randint(1, 6)
            if con == 1:
                mut = a
            elif con == 2:
                mut = b
            elif con == 3:
                mut = c     
            elif con == 4:
                lower_or_higher = r.randint(0, 1)
                if lower_or_higher == 0:
                    mut = self.alphabet_lower[d]
                elif lower_or_higher == 1:
                    mut = self.alphabet_upper[d]
            elif con == 5:
                lower_or_higher = r.randint(0, 1)
                if lower_or_higher == 0:
                    mut = self.alphabet_lower[e]
                elif lower_or_higher == 1:
                    mut = self.alphabet_upper[e]
            elif con == 6:
                lower_or_higher = r.randint(0, 1)
                if lower_or_higher == 0:
                    mut = self.alphabet_lower[f]
                elif lower_or_higher == 1:
                    mut = self.alphabet_upper[f]

            self.mutated_seed.append(mut)

def Display():  
    os.system("cls")    
    user_input = int(raw_input("Length of password: "))
    mutate_seed = MutateSeed(user_input, alpha_lower, alpha_upper)
    mutate_seed.mutate_seed()
    display_pass = "".join(str(x) for x in mutate_seed.mutated_seed)
    f = open('PasswordFile.txt', 'a+')  
    f.write(display_pass)
    f.write("\n")
    print "\n" "Your Password: "+display_pass+ "\n"
    raw_input("Press Enter to continue: ")
    pass
while True:
    Display()
```

Comment: Depends in large part on the quality of the PRNG `random` implements, i imagine.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I was hoping someone knew what that was...

Comment: The most common weakness with things like this is lack of entropy in the initial seed. If (for example) you start with a 32-bit integer for the initial seed, somebody can simply cycle through all possible inputs.

Comment: So maybe I should write something that makes the algorithm change every time the program is run, like have the main program run a "generate_new_process" script once complete?

Comment: I would write something that uses a known secure generator, with an exceptionally long period, and (probably) seed it from a true random number source. The most common type of secure PRNG is an encryption algorithm in counter mode.

Comment: @FrigidDev "So maybe I should write something that makes the algorithm change every time the program is run..." Why do you think that would help? If it uses the same random number source, it's not giving you any more entropy, just an algorithm that's harder to analyze.

Comment: Just take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html): "Warning: The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. Use `os.urandom()` or `SystemRandom` if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy&pasting code multiple times does not make it more secure. If we clean up your `mutate_seed` method, we'd end up with this:

```
def mutate_seed(self):
    for x in range(self.seed):
        number_or_letter = r.randint(0, 1)
        if number_or_letter:
            self.mutated_seed.append(r.randint(0, 9))
        else:
            lower_or_higher = r.randint(0, 1)
            if lower_or_higher:
                self.mutated_seed.append(r.choice(self.alphabet_lower))
            else:
                self.mutated_seed.append(r.choice(self.alphabet_upper))
```

Quick Notes on the changes:

- I don't request random values which I don't end up using. Throwing away values from the random number generator does not make those numbers that you use more secure.
- I don't use single-letter variable names or abbreviations like `con` or `mut` that obscure the meaning.
- `random.choice` is so simple and nice – consider using it.
- This solution features far less duplicate code. Did you calculate `r.ranint(1, 6)` as an analogy for six-sided dice?

Now the code is cleaned up so that we can do some more substantial reviewing.

There is no use in separating between numbers, lowercase letters, and uppercase letters. They all should be in the same character pool so that each character has the same probability of occuring at each position in the password. With your current methods, a digit is much more likely to occur than any given letter, simply because there are less digits than letters.

So we should have something like

```
lower = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)] # I can't be bothered to type
upper = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)] #   out all letters manually
digits = [str(x) for x in range(0, 9)]
character_pool = lower + upper + digits
...
password = [random.choice(character_pool) for _ in range(0, length)]
```

The interface of your class is horrible. We have to create an instance, then call the `mutate_seed` method, then access an instance variable, then must join that array to a string until we can finally display it. Consider packing all of this functionality into a single, convenient function instead:

```
def make_password(length, *collections_of_characters):
    # join all character collections into a single set
    characters = set()
    for collection in collections_of_characters:
        characters.update(str(c) for c in collection)
    characters = list(characters)

    password = [random.choice(characters) for _ in range(0, length)]
    return "".join(password)
```

Then using this is as simple as

```
password = make_password(10,
                         "0123456789",
                         "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 
                         "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
print(password)
```

If you need a certain set of characters more often, put those into a list:

```
alphanumeric_chars = ["0123456789",
                      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 
                      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
password = make_password(10, *alphanumeric_chars)
print(password)
```

or create a wrapper function:

```
def make_alphanumeric_password(length):
    return make_password(length,
                         "0123456789",
                         "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 
                         "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
print(make_alphanumeric_password(10))
```

Not all abstractions map cleanly to classes.

Your code uses the word “seed” quite often. A seed is the initial state of a random number generator. When set to the same seed each time, the random number generator will produce the same sequence of numbers. In your class, “seed” seems to mean “length” instead. Use clear, obvious names for your variables rather than using technical lingo if you aren't sure what it means – although a [quick trip to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_%28randomness%29) would have cleared that up.

You issue a few Windows-only system commands such as `cls`. Unless this is central to the working of your application, don't manipulate the console, such as setting the color or clearing the screen. Users can do this themselves if they want to. Removing these commands also makes your code usable on other operating systems like OS X or Linux.

You are using the `random` library as a random number generator. The numbers produced by this library aren't really random, they are just pseudo-random. This is usually not an issue as long as a really random seed is chosen, but because the number sequence is derived algorithmically, it should not be used for really really important stuff. Most passwords are only important and not really really important, so this should be fine ;-) but it's good to remember that real randomness is something different.

That is one aspect where the security of your program is not optimal, but good enough. Writing the password to a file is however absolutely irresponsible. When the password is only displayed on the command line, we can assume that it will only be immediately visible until the screen is cleared or other content has caused it to scroll out of sight. It will be held in memory for a while longer, but at least a rebooting of the system will remove any trace of this.
A plain text file however is much more persistent (it stays there after a reboot). It is also much easier for other users to access that password. Don't store secrets at all, or if you have to store them, secure them properly.

You should consider writing your Python code so that it is usable both as a module, and a script. For this, we first write all definitions that should be usable as a module, and at the end add an `if __name__ == '__main__'` section, which will only be executed if the file was invoked as a script. Now we can both do:

```
# in some other program:
import make_password as mp
random_hex = mp.make_password(10, "0123456789abcdef")
```

or

```
python make_password.py
```

to use the functionality of your code. Designing for code reuse is a generally good idea.

Comment: Wow, that is really comprehensive and useful, and is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Oh, and random.choice is AWESOME, thank you!

Comment: I didn't even know it existed... :)

Comment: @FrigidDev Re: `random.choice` – neither did I know about it until I re-read the `random` docs to find out whether the `randint` boundaries were inclusive or exclusive. 200_success seems to have a similar find in his answer with the `string.ascii_lowercase` constant which I didn't know about either. Reviewing code means everyone involved learns :)

Comment: There is one problem with picking the characters uniformly from the union of the input strings. Many websites and other password-demanding systems impose a requirement that at least one character from each of a number of character classes be included in the password. If you redefine the contract so the method's return will contain at least one character from each string passed to it, the potential utility of the function would be far greater.

Comment: @AJMansfield good point. For an 8-character password composed of numbers, uppercase, and lowercase, there is  currently a 25% chance it won't contain any numbers, and a 1% chance it won't contain any uppercase letters. With the original implementation, this would have been 0.4% and 10%, respectively. Adjusting the distributions is not a solution and makes the password more predictable. Instead, one could write a wrapper that discards passwords until one meets the requirements. Unfortunately that algorithm wouldn't be guaranteed to halt.

Comment: -1 for implying that using a non-cryptographic random source is good enough.

Comment: @eBusiness “good enough” depends on what we're trying to achieve, and what we're defending against. A secret does not have to be generated via a cryptography-grade RNG to enhance your security. I use a similar Perl script to generate my passwords, which increases my security as it limits password reuse across web sites. If a hash of one of my passwords is leaked and cracked, other accounts remain secure. In theory RNG weaknesses could be used to accelerate cracking, but that doesn't bother me. I'm not defending against advanced persistent threats, just against run-of-the-mill breaches.

Comment: @eBusiness The quality of the randomness may not be the only concern. Any of the passwords generated by this program already would be _much_ more random than a human-picked one, and that might be good enough. Humans are the weakest link when it comes to password security. One might ask instead, for example, are these outputs memorable?

Comment: You are making an unqualified assumption about the importance of these passwords. If this review is to make any sense you have to assume that the output actually matters, otherwise any of the flaws are acceptable. And really, all it takes to patch this is to replace one random function with another, it is literally easier to just make the code safe than to discuss the need. What you are doing is to promote a bad practice that has absolutely no reason to exist beyond lack of knowledge.

Comment: @eBusiness If you need to protect against a case where an attacker obtains several dozen passwords generated during one session, then yes, it may in fact not be acceptable. (Although more because of the 'password' part than anything to do with the RNG...) Python's random library is actually very good, and is certainly suitable for generating passwords to use for any internets one needs.

Comment: @AJMansfield That depends on the environment, if Python for some reason can't get a proper seed it will silently fall back to using system time as seed, thus greatly limiting the possible passwords to an attacker who can guess approximately when the password was generated. Better write code that fails if there is no cryptographic random source present than code that silently falls back to an insecure option. amons password generator will of course not be able to output anything but one of 2 billion options as the Perl rng hasn't got a bigger internal state.

Comment: `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')` This is a multi-os way to clear the terminal output.

Answer (score 8):

### Expected behaviour / User experience

- Logging passwords to a file in unhashed, unencrypted form is bad practice.  Doing so without telling the user is a sin.
- Using `cls` to clear the screen is [non-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2084508/115710).
- There is no clean way to exit the infinite loop in your program.  I think that the following conditions should all trigger a clean exit:

  - <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (keyboard interrupt)
  - <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (end of file)
  - Entering `0` or a negative number for the password length
  - Entering a non-numeric value for the password length

### The code

- `MutateSeed` is a weird name for the class; `mutate_seed` is a weird name for the method.  There is no seeding going on.  Furthermore, there is no point in the "mutation" (appending more characters to a previously generated password).
- There's no point in making a class.  There is also no point in accepting parameters `alpha_lower` and `alpha_upper`.  A simple `generate_password(length)` function would be just as good.
- The `mutated_seed` array consists of some one-digit integers and some one-character strings.  It would be better to make them all the same data type, i.e. all one-character strings.  Better yet, why not make it more convenient for the caller and just return a string?
- The set of all characters is available as [`string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).
- You are working too hard.  For each character, you want to pick a digit with 50% probability, and a letter with 50% probability.  Instead of deciding on uppercase/lowercase, then deciding on a letter, just pick from among 52 letters.
- By making digits appear with 50% probability, you've made digits overrepresented.  You would actually get better security if you choose from among all characters with equal probability, i.e. digits with probability \$\dfrac{10}{10 + 26 + 26}\$, uppercase with probability  \$\dfrac{26}{10 + 26 + 26}\$, and lowercase with probability \$\dfrac{26}{10 + 26 + 26}\$.

### Suggested implementation

Mostly preserving the original behaviour…

```
from random import choice
import os
import platform
import string

def clear_screen():
    os.system(['clear', 'cls'][platform.system() == 'Windows'])

def generate_password(length):
    CHAR_POOLS = [string.digits, string.ascii_letters]
    return ''.join(choice(choice(CHAR_POOLS)) for _ in range(length))

try:
    while True:
        clear_screen()
        password_length = int(raw_input("Length of password: "))
        if password_length <= 0:
            break
        password = generate_password(password_length)
        print "\nYour password: %s\n" % (password)
        raw_input("Press Enter to continue: ")
except (ValueError, KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError) as exit_on_invalid_input:
    print '',
```

Comment: A good review, two points though: **(1)** If `CHAR_POOLS` were defined as `string.digits + string.ascii_letters`  rather than a list, you wouldn't need to call `choice` twice, making the code a little easier to read. **(2)** I disagree that there is no point in accepting the alphabet as a parameter. If `CHAR_POOLS` could be passed as a parameter, the method would be much more versatile, for instance allowing the caller to request a password containing symbols as well (as in [my recent review of another password-generating question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48462/9390)).

Comment: @codesparkle I call `choice()` twice to preserve the probability distribution of the original code. Yes, parameterizing the character repertoire would make it more flexible. In that case, it should be an optional rather than a required parameter.